# How do we get envelope recipient header using fuglu plugins?

Tags: python-3.x

Using fuglu plugin and python, trying to parse thru' the suspect, i am trying to get the envelope recipients. eg. Sometimes I can send TO: members@domain.com, xyz@anotherdomain.com
How does fuglu decide who is the envelope recipient when members@domain.com is a group mail id

Postfix has already translated the group to individual ids on incoming relay server before it reaches the outgoing server with this fuglu plugin.

I need to access the envelope recipient address only. How can I get this value in fuglu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fuglu, you can get the list of envelope recipients using `suspect.recipients`.
Now from your question it seems like a message may previously have been sent to `group@example.com` and this group adress then rewrites to `recipient1@example.com`, `recipient2@example.com`, ...

Which one of these adresses fuglu sees in `suspect.recipients` depends on your mailserver/routing configuration. I understand that fuglu in your case runs on a second mailserver where the alias has already been expanded, so `suspect.recipients` will likely not contain `group@example.com` .
It may contain either all or only some of the expanded adresses if the server is configured to handle multiple recipients in the same transaction or if the mailserver is configured to split up the recipients ( `destination_recipient_limit` in postfix for example).

If your goal is to extract the *original* recipient address (`group@example.com`), this is actually quite hard, as this information may not even be available in the SMTP transaction anymore. Some servers write it into a received header:

```
Received: from [...]
        by your.relay.example.com with SMTPS id blabla
        for <group@example.com>
```

and in this case you could extract it from there with some regex magic. But if your inbound server does not add the `for <original recipient>` part you're out of luck. In this case you could fall back to extracting the `To:` header from the message using `suspect.get_message_rep().get('To')` ), which *likely* contains the original envelope recipient, but unfortunately this is not guaranteed.